# G++ missing -lgcmt-lib when compiling

Tags: .net, g++

I following a tutorial at https://csnative.codeplex.com/, Quick Start, try to compiler C# IL code to exe using .Net Native.
In the second step, **compile exe file** which use G++, I got this error message

{MyLocalPathHere}/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcmt-lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I can't findout anything about -lgcmt-lib in google.
Looking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) download any file from http://csnative.codeplex.com/releases/view/132421
2) Open archive il2c_10082015.7z and search for file *libgcmt-lib.a*
3) Put it in the folder in option "-L"

Additionally you can compile the library yourself.

1) Open site http://www.hboehm.info/gc/
2) Follow instructions to compile the library

Comment: Thankyou very much. I followed the 1st way and its worked.